# Do I always have to write the argument names in SmartPy tests?

Tags: smartpy

I defined an entrypoint with 2 arguments:

```
  @sp.entrypoint
  def update(self, newx, newy):
    self.data.x = newx
    self.data.y = newy
```

then I wrote a test of this entrypoint:

```
  scenario += contract.update(newx = 4, newy = 3)
```

Do I always have to write the argument names?  Why is `contract.update(4, 3)` not possible?

Question from Slack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a long-standing problem.

This may change in a future update associated with the new syntax.

> Do I always have to write the argument names?

Yes, you always have to write the argument names. There are two ways to do that:

1. Naming the arguments explicitly.
2. Sending a record with the two arguments.

> Why is contract.update(4, 3) not possible?

Tezos entrypoints accept only one argument. SmartPy treats entrypoints with multiple arguments as entrypoints with a record argument.

The following entrypoint is functionally equivalent to your example:

```
@sp.entrypoint
def update(self, param):
    self.data.x = param.x
    self.data.y = param.y
```

It's not clear if it would still make sense to call this entrypoint with contract.update(4, 3). The main issue with this approach is the order of the arguments. It becomes even more challenging when you consider that custom layouts can change the order:

```
@sp.entrypoint(parameter_type = sp.TRecord(a=sp.TNat, b=sp.TNat).layout(("b", "a")))
def update(self, param):
    self.data.x = param.x
    self.data.y = param.y
```

In conclusion, you always need to provide the argument names when calling entrypoints with multiple parameters to ensure the correct mapping of values to their corresponding parameters. This limitation may be addressed in a future update of SmartPy.